# What happens when ios::in mode is specified with an output file stream?

Tags: c++, io, file-handling, filestream

What is the purpose of `ios::in` and `ios::out` modes while creating file streams in c++? I have created an output file stream as
`ofstream myout("file.txt",ios::in);`  This is an output file stream but `ios::in` mode is specified. What is the effect of `ios::in` mode in output stream and similarly `ios::out` mode in input file stream?

I have looked [here](https://cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/files/), but couldn't understand.

Comment: "*I have looked [at cplusplus.com], but couldn't understand*" - that is because cplusplus.com is a lousy site to learn from. Use cppreference.com instead.

Answer (score 2):

Per [`std::basic_filebuf<CharT,Traits>::open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open), which better explains what the various flag combinations actually do:

> The file is opened as if by calling `std::fopen` with the second argument (mode) determined as follows:
>
> | mode | openmode & ~ate | Action if file already exists | Action if file does not exist |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | "r" | `in` | Read from start | Failure to open |
> | "w" | `out`, `out|trunc` | Destroy contents | Create new |
> | "a" | `app`, `out|app` | Append to file | Create new |
> | "r+" | `out|in` | Read from start | Error |
> | "w+" | `out|in|trunc` | Destroy contents | Create new |
> | "a+" | `out|in|app`, `in|app` | Write to end | Create new |
> | "rb" | `binary|in` | Read from start | Failure to open |
> | "wb" | `binary|out`, `binary|out|trunc` | Destroy contents | Create new |
> | "ab" | `binary|app`, `binary|out|app` | Write to end | Create new |
> | "r+b" | `binary|out|in` | Read from start | Error |
> | "w+b" | `binary|out|in|trunc` | Destroy contents | Create new |
> | "a+b" | `binary|out|in|app`, `binary|in|app` | Write to end | Create new |
>
> If `openmode` is not one of the modes listed, the `open()` fails.
>
> If the open operation succeeds and `openmode & std::ios_base::ate != 0` (the ate bit is set), repositions the file position to the end of file, as if by calling `std::fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, where `file` is the pointer returned by calling `fopen`. If the repositioning fails, calls `close()` and returns a null pointer to indicate failure.
>
> If the associated file was already open, returns a null pointer right away.

Comment: `std::ofstream` will additionally always add `std::ios_base::out` to the mode (both the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) and the [`open()` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) do this); likewise `std::ifstream` will always add `std::ios_base::in` to the mode. `std::fstream` is the only file-stream that passes the mode as-is to the filebuf. So for `std::ofstream myout("file.txt",std::ios_base::in);` the behaviour would be equivalent to `out|in` as listed in the table above.